# What is the experimental feature "indexed members"?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

On the new [Roslyn Preview site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) it mentions being able to try out potential language features, and lists three such features.

[image: screenshot]

The first two I've heard of before (for example [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated)), but I can't figure out from the code sample what "indexed members" are. Can anyone explain what these are, either based on another source or the code sample? (It's worth nothing `$x` is not a valid identifier in C# 5.)

**UPDATE** - According to the [Roslyn Feature Status](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status) page, this feature has been withdrawn.

Comment: Yes withdrawn. [The discussion here](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/541566)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.$foobar` is just short form for `["foobar"]`

Comment: @NealGafter - Is this the same feature that is (was?) referred to as "lightweight dynamic member access"? Is there a dynamic aspect to this feature? For example, in this post: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540574#post1230055 Thanks!

Comment: .$foobar is indeed a short form for ["foobar"]. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22881736/855651 makes it more clear